# How do I get "Calling package doesn't have carrier privilege to this profile" Is it possible to develop an app that eliminates the error?

Tags: android, profile, uicc

・We are developing a native app that runs on Android to sell eSIM as an agent for each communication carrier.
・Implement a function to install eSIM profile information in this application
・With this function, customers want to realize a seamless user experience and make it easy to use eSIM.
・Implementation of this function is assumed to be realized by euiccManager.downloadSubscription ・The following error is returned at the time of writing
"Calling package doesn't have carrier privilege to this profile"
・The account under development has been registered as a Google developer.
・I am using a certificate that I created myself.
I would like to know how to solve

How do I get "Calling package doesn't have carrier privilege to this profile"
Is it possible to develop an app that eliminates the error and installs the esim profile?

I read this document but could not solve

https://source.android.com/docs/core/connect/uicc?hl=ja